# Select from two databases - Union but retain all headers

Tags: mysql, union

I have searched for help on this but nothing quite fits what I'm after, though I'm sure it must have been asked before.

```
Table 1 - table1
table1.date (date), table1.name (varchar(20))

Table 2 - table2
table2.date (date), table2.regnum (int(10))
```

I am trying to display a full list of the data from both tables ordered by date.

The data is not connected in any way, so I think JOIN is the wrong method.

When I use UNION, I get an issue with the output because the second column is a cross between varchar and int.

Is it possible to use UNION to end up with a result where only the date is merged while the other headers remain seperate.  Example:

```
date (date), name (varchat(20)), regnum (int(10))
```

Obviously any data from table1 would have NULL in the regnum field where any data from table2 would have NULL in the name field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the values into separate columns for the `union` operation:

```
select date, name, cast(NULL as signed) as regnum
from table1
union all
select date, NULL, regnum
from table2;
```

The `cast()` shouldn't be necessary but it clarifies what you are trying to do.

Also:  you should generally use `union all` unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: Had trouble using this with cast, but dropped that part and it worked as I wanted.  Thanks for the tip on UNION ALL also.